# Stateless Beam pipeline with Flink runner - pubsublite messages getting ack'ed befor being written to Kafka

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I'm a newcomer to both Beam/Flink. So not sure if this question is related to Beam or to Flink. We are setting up to run Beam application using Flink runner.

I have a fairly stateless streaming application without any aggregation/states. I am basically reading from Pubsublite and do some simple transformation of data, generate a ProducerRecord of it and submit it to be two separate Kafka topics. All my experiments has been successful so far and I even got it to work locally using Minikube/Flink K8s operator etc.

Unfortunately, I am stuck in a stage where I am unable to figure out the right docs/topics to read to understand the issue. If there is any error while saving to Kafka or if Kafka is available, it seems the Pubsublite message is ack'ed before being successfully saved into Kafka. If I restart my app after failure or anything, the original pubsublite message is not reprocessed or resent to Kafka. I am losing data in that case as it seems the message has already been ack'ed in the previous step (I can also see there is no backlog from Google cloud console).

Ideally, my goal is that the message is only ack'ed after we have saved it to both the Kafka of if it is ack'ed before, then the state is saved locally and after restart Beam/Flink will retry just sending it to Kafka.

I initially though the way to do this is to use some form of checkpoints/savepoints but looks like they are more for stateless streaming application. Am I misunderstanding the concept?

My current code is simply:

```
msgs.apply("Map pubsubmessage to producerrecord", MapElements.via(new FormatPubSubMessage(options.getTopic())))
        .setCoder(ProducerRecordCoder.of(VoidCoder.of(), ByteArrayCoder.of()))
        .apply("Write to primary kafka topic", KafkaIO.<Void, byte[]>writeRecords()
                .withBootstrapServers(options.getBootstrapServers())
                .withTopic(options.getTopic())
                .withKeySerializer(VoidSerializer.class)
                .withValueSerializer(ByteArraySerializer.class)
        );
```

Any pointers to docs/concepts on how one would go about achieving it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to use the checkpoint system even if it's "stateless". Refer to the docs at:
[Apache Beam Flink runners Streaming Execution](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/#streaming-execution)

So with that, I setup Flink's *checkpoint directory* option and it works now.